# Container with height 100% fits content, unset height sets the height to 100% of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a case with the `height` property is css.

According to the [definition] (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) a container with `height: 50%`

> Set the height of an element to 50% of the height of the parent
>   element

Here are 2 code snippets, where the only difference is the height property set to 100% or not set at all

With height property set:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/2kzLtedm/17/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 30px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without height property set (Working as intended): [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/2kzLtedm/19/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 30px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For me this works opposite of the definiton of the height property, how come?
I have noticed that without `display: flex` in the parent the behaviour is different, but then `height: 100%` does nothing.

Comment: tl:dr from the duplicate : without height:100% you have the stretch effect of flexbox .. with height:100% you fail to auto value because you cannot use percentage since parent don't have a height defined

Comment: as a side note, the definition of w3school isn't complete, you will find the complete on in the duplicate taken from the spec